# Extending simplicial maps between filtrations to homology groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-complex, topological-data-analysis

Suppose I have 2 filtrations of simplicial complexes $K,G$: $\{K_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}},\{G_{\beta}\}_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}}$. Here, $K_{\alpha}$ is a subcomplex of $K$ and if $\alpha\leq\beta$ then $K_{\alpha}\subseteq K_{\beta}$.

Because of this filtration, we have the following persistence module of homology groups:

$$
i:H_d(K_{\alpha})\rightarrow H_d(K_{\beta}) 
$$
where $i$ is the homology map induced by the inclusion map $K_{\alpha}\subseteq K_{\beta}$. We have a similar persistence module for the filtration $\{G_{\beta}\}_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}}$.

Now, suppose we have a simplicial map $f:K\rightarrow G$ such that $f(K_{\alpha})\subseteq G_{\alpha+\epsilon}$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. In the following paper, (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.3885.pdf, Pg 4, Ex 2.2), and others I have read, this simplicial map induces chain maps between $H_d(K_{\alpha})$ and $H^{\epsilon}_d(G_{\alpha})$. $H^{\epsilon}_d(G_{\alpha})$ is just the chain of modules $H_d(G_{\alpha})$ shifted down by $\epsilon$.

In other words, for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a $\phi_{\alpha}:H_d(K_{\alpha})\rightarrow H_d(G_{\alpha+\epsilon})$ that would satisfy the usual commutative properties after shifting the chain.

However, I don't see how such a map $\phi_{\alpha}$ can be defined. Firstly, if we have a n-simplex $[v_0,...,v_n]$, $[f(v_0),...,f(v_n)]$ need not be a $n$-simplex. Secondly, if $y\in\ker(\partial_{\alpha}:C_{d}(K_{\alpha})\rightarrow C_{d-1}(K_{\alpha}))$ how do we know that $f(y)\in \ker(\partial_{\alpha}:C_{d}(G_{\alpha+\epsilon})\rightarrow C_{d-1}(G_{\alpha+\epsilon}))$.

Does someone know how such a chain map arises?

Comment: Isn't it simply true that if $f\colon K\to G$ is a simplicial map, then also $f\colon K_a\to G_{a+\epsilon}$ is a simplicial map? If so, you can take the induced map on simplicial homology.

Comment: yeah but $[v_0,..,v_n]$ is a $n$-simplex that could be mapped to a $l-$simplex where $l<n$ in which case the image of a n-chain i.e $\sum z_if(a_i)$ need not be a $n$-chain

Comment: If $[f(v_0),\ldots,f(v_n)]$ is an $l$-simplex with $l<n$, then this means that the $f(v_i)$ are not all distinct and then by definition this $n$-chain is mapped to zero. This is stated for instance in the Wikipedia article on simplicial homology.

Comment: thanks. but how do you show that kernel elements remain kernel elements

Comment: Any simplicial map induces a chain map and any chain map between chain complexes induces a map on homology. You might want to read up on homological algebra and simplicial/cellular/singular homology before reading papers such as the one you linked, because they usually assume readers know the answers to the kind of questions you are asking. This is usually covered in the standard textbooks on algebraic topology and homological algebra.